# Is this slow because of knockout.js or jquery UI dialog?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

In my real web-app I have a tree that displays folders, and in some cases I display this tree inside a jQuery UI Dialog.  I've stripped out everything I could and put an example of the issue in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shopguy/gRbef/

If you click button 1, it toggles the dialog visibility.

If you click button 2, it toggles the in-line (no dialog) list visibility.

Doing most of my testing in Firefox.  Clicking button 1 takes about 1.5 seconds, to show OR hide (even hiding is slow).  Clicking button 2 is pretty much instant.

**Is this an issue with jQuery UI Dialog.  Does it do a lot with the DOM on each hide/show?  Or it just an issue because I have it inside a template?  Does KO recreate the dom just because it is in a template like that?**

Both cases uses templates, but the dialog version has one extra template, for the dialog itself.  They both use templates for the sub-folders though... since I'm not sure how else to do recursive tree-like layouts with KO.

This is the main HTML from the fiddle showing my dialog w/ tree layout:

```
<div data-bind="jqDialog: {autoOpen: false, modal: false, width: 350, height: 400, minWidth: 350, minHeight: 300 }, template: { name: 'folderDetailsTemplate' } , openDialog: dlg1"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="folderDetailsTemplate">
List<br />
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl1', foreach: folders}"></ul>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl1">
<li>
    <a data-bind="visible: expanded">-</a>
    <a data-bind="visible: !expanded">+</a>
    <a>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </a>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl1', foreach: folders}">
    </ul>
</li>
</script>
```

This is the script:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).dialog(options);
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.openDialog = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (value) {
                $(element).dialog("open");
            } else {
                $(element).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }

    function Folder(i, l) {
        this.name = "Test Folder " + i;
        this.folders = ko.observableArray();
        this.expanded = true;

        if (i < 4 && l < 4) {
            var fs = new Array();
            for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                var f = new Folder(x, l + 1);
                fs.push(f);
            }
            this.folders(fs);
        }

    }

    var vm = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.folders = ko.observableArray();
        var fs = new Array();
        for (var x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            var f = new Folder(x, 0);
            fs.push(f);
        }
        self.folders(fs);
        self.dlg1 = ko.observable();
        self.list1 = ko.observable();

        self.test1 = function () {
            self.dlg1(!self.dlg1());
        }

        self.test2 = function () {
            self.list1(!self.list1());
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new vm());
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem nearly as slow as you report for me in Firefox. The dialog is clearly slower, but it's not that bad.

Comment: Sounds about right, my PC is a bit older, running XP still.  AMD Dual Core 2.3ghz CPU, 2GB ram.  This is a critical area of my app though, and new to KO/jQuery, so want to make sure I start out with a good design.

Comment: removing the template for the dialog (moving the dialog inside the div tag and only having the 2nd template, not the first) does make it super fast, so it has something to do with that.  jsFiddle is having issues right now, so unable to update that to show example of my changes.  Might post that as 1 possible answer when I can, but would like an answer that includes more low-level knowledge to help me and others understand the root issue here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shopguy/gRbef/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's making it slow is that the `openDialog` and `template` bindings are grouped together in the binding string of the same element. So each time `openDialog` is updated, the template binding is updated too and re-renders your template. I like to just put the template binding in a nested comment binding like this:

```
<div data-bind="jqDialog: {autoOpen: false, modal: false, width: 350, height: 400, minWidth: 350, minHeight: 300 }, openDialog: dlg1">
        <!-- ko template: 'folderDetailsTemplate' --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

This is all detailed very nicely here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html